# The preimage of a $\sigma$-ring is a $\sigma$-ring

Tags: measure-theory

> If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $W$ is a $\sigma$-ring of subsets of $Y$, prove that all subsets of the form $f^{-1}(B)$ with $B\in W$ form a $\sigma$-ring $Z$ of subsets of $X$.

I just want to ask about the proof that $f^{-1}(B_1)-f^{-1}(B_2)\in Z$. We have that $f^{-1}(B_1)-f^{-1}(B_2) = f^{-1}(B_1-B_2)$ and that $B_1-B_2\in W$. What I don't see is how to connect $B_1-B_2\in W$ with the fact that then $f^{-1}(B_1-B_2)\in Z$.

Comment: The crucial thing here is the equality $f^{-1}(B_1)-f^{-1}(B_2)=f^{-1}(B_1-B_2)$. It shows that the collection of sets $f^{-1}(B)$ where $B\in W$ is closed under set difference.

Comment: But does it really affect something if $B_1-B_2$ is not in $W$, i.e. that the ring $W$ does not exist? I think the identity is true regardless if $W$ exists or not.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But.. *if* a $\sigma$-ring $W$ on $Y$ and an arbitrary function $f:X\to Y$ are given, then the preimages constitute a $\sigma$-ring on $X$. That's what it says, and the proof uses this generic identity.